# Compressing huge files (> 2GB) into ZIP on the client side

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, upload, compression

Im building an upload tool using `node.js` and `socket.io`, because they usually upload incredibly huge files and normal upload forms wouldnt work. The problem is that they wanted to compress the files into a zip before sending them, to increase efficiency in transmission.

I've been researching around compression methods like [JSZip](http://stuartk.com/jszip/) or [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/), but neither of those work well with extremely big files. What could I do?

Comment: Why ZIP? Can you use another algorighm? Can you make a Flash uploader?

Comment: ZIP because its the most widely accepted. I rather not use Flash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can compress up to 4GB of data with [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/) but:

- it will work only with Chrome
- it will be quite slow (approx. 30min per GB of compressed data on my old laptop)

You can try it online with [this demo](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/demos/demo1.html). You must select the "HDD" option in the "choose temporary storage" input. Then you can import big files from your filesystem and monitor the memory consumption: it should be stable (approx. 300MB on my laptop).

Selecting "HDD" means that zip.js will use [File API: Directories and System](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/) to store compressed data. This API is currently only available on Chrome and allows to write data into a sandboxed virtual filesystem. The demo uses the temporary storage which does not require a user permission.

Edit: You could also implement your own [Writer constructor](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/core-api.html#zip-writer) function to stream the data to your server while zip.js compresses it: it wouldn't rely on the filesystem API and should work on every browser you support. A Writer must just implement these 2 methods:

```
init(callback[, onerror])
// initializes the stream where to write the zipped data

writeUint8Array(array, callback[, onerror])
// writes asynchronously a Uint8Array into the stream.

// getData method is optional
```

Here is [an example](https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/zip.js/issues/21#issuecomment-9889885) of custom Writer and Reader constructors. You can also look at [zip.js Writers implementations](https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/zip.js/blob/f4b6ffbe0b1a503730e9a5b20eda287812b9df87/WebContent/zip.js#L279-401) for more examples.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a compressor on the client side I'm sorry to tell you that JS is not the way to go.

A side from that, your best bet is to tell your users to just compress the files before uploading them. Or even use some other kind of tool (FTP maybe?).

EDIT:

Oh, btw, ZIP is really inefficient with random data, so you'll be wasting CPU time for the compression/decompression and you won't shrink almost nothing in size.

Comment: There is added functionality in the tool, that I didnt comment. Thats why I didnt chose FTP, which would be the obvious option for this kind of operation. Are there Flash "compressors"?

Comment: @Dbugger not aware of any. Random data is what your users will probably upload. You see, compressing a text file is way different than compressing photos, music, videos, etc... Text files usually get awesome ratio compression while binary files don't (usually). But you better test that yourself (and maybe read about file compression?)

Comment: Then what's the point in compressing something knowing that it won't get any smaller? If you just need to make it *look* like it's doing something, then yes, use one of the libraries you found.

Comment: I really think you should understand better how compression works before doing anything further. A "DVD image" could be compressed to a few bytes depending on what type of data is inside that DVD image. So, please, understand what you're asking before continuing.

Comment: I dont want to steer off-topic and discuss about compression use cases. I'll take in mind your answer, but I'll wait if anyone has something else that could be helpful.

Comment: @Dbugger - since you've removed the comment that stated it was as a direct result of requirements, are we to assume that they've changed? If not, why remove the comment?

Comment: Ive removed them because they are off-topic to my question, and I wanted to keep them thread clean. Id appreciate if you'd do the same.