# Node.js zlib.deflate hangs forever on larger data

Tags: node.js, zip, compression, zlib, freeze

I have a dictionary data, that I need to convert to JSON, **compress** (zip) and send over the network.

It all works fine, till json reaches a certain size (15MB). At which point the gzip never executes a callback and hangs forever. (deflate() does the same)

Any advice or help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
      var json = JSON.stringify(data);

      zlib.gzip( json , (err, buffer) => {
           true;        
      })
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compressing huge files (> 2GB) into ZIP on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271061/compressing-huge-files-2gb-into-zip-on-the-client-side)

Comment: You're not doing anything in the callback -- is it invoked with an error?